# How to use facebook share inside the recyclerview

Tags: android

I need to share my app link on Facebook, but I don't know how to call share dialog and `onactivityresult` method inside the `recyclerview` adapter.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot share text alone without using Facebook SDK

Facebook ignores plain text sharing using intents, BUT you can share any url.

Note:-if you share text it wont show there, but url will show, you can share simple image or video though

Use the following code in your recyclerview adapter

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.google.com");
PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList)
{
  if ((app.activityInfo.name).startsWith("com.whatsapp"))// for facebook("com.facebook.katana") but it wont work use SDK
  {
   final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
   final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
   shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
   shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
   shareIntent.setComponent(name);
   getApplicationContext().startActivity(shareIntent);
   break;
   }
 }
```

Here is the [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android) where you can learn in deep about Facebook SDK and how can you share content from your android app to facebook

Comment: startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "share using"));  this code shows list of applications.But i need to show only facebook.

Comment: Like i said , it is not possible to share to facebook without using facebook SDK, i tried this code i was able to send to whatsapp alone but not to facebook. Check my edits

Comment: What is activityList?

Comment: The for loop condition tells to search for all available list of application, and then we set condition in if, i.e if it starts with com.whatsapp we execute our code, hope you understand if u did make sure you accept and vote the answer